# Friendly URL's returns 404

Tags: .htaccess

Hello everyone.
I have a problem with my htaccess file. I made friendly url's but server returns 404 error and i can't find where i made mistake in code. I spent 3 hours on it and still nothing. I'm begging you for help guys :D

Here's my code:

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+)$ /$1.php [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+).(php|html|htm)$ /$1 [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index.(php|html|htm)$ / [R=301,L]
```

Redirect is making good but server returns 404 error instead display website.

I want to make urls like example below:

From:
www.domain.com/customers.php
www.domain.com/products/number1.php

To:
www.domain.com/customers
www.domain.com/products/number1

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved this but now i have a redirect loop :(

New code:

```
    Options -Indexes
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+).(php|html|htm)$ /$1 [NC,R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^index.(php|html|htm)$ / [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 RewriteOptions inherit
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```